# IF with RANDBETWEEN in same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hey I need to use both RANDBETWEEN and IF function in same cell?
I have to generate random data, but if the cell value is 0 then I also need the random value to be 0..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, do you realize that `RANDBETWEEN()` function will generate *new and new value every time when you open your workbook* (and every time when you worksheet will be *recalculated*, e. g. by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> , so you will NOT have something as *constant random value forever*?

So suppose that the cell `A1` contains a value by which the random value is generated - if it is nonzero. Then the formula (in some other cell) will be

```
=IF(A1=0, 0, RANDBETWEEN(50, 60))
```

Comment: yeah! it has to be totally randomised because it's a business sales simulation and we have to use assumptions - this totally worked though thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider to accept my answer (click on the check mark) if it was useful for you.

Comment: To supplement @MarianD's comment, by accepting an answer (your question was clearly answered) you will let others know you no longer need help.

Comment: Hey! just another one re RANDBETWEEN, say I only want it to be either 0 or 10, nothing in between?

Comment: Use `10 * RANDBETWEEN(0, 1)` instead of `RANDBETWEEN(50, 60)`

Comment: If you want 0 when A1 is 0 and 10 otherwise, use `= IF(A1=0, 0, 10)`.

Comment: is it possible to use text rather than numbers in the formula? e.g. (own, public)?

Comment: (I'm making a dashboard and am in the stages of data entry - it has to be random - you guys are a HUGE help!)

Comment: `=IF(RANDBETWEEN(0, 1) = 0, "own", "public")`